# Smooth scroll to #anchor from another page

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to animate the smooth scroll effect with jquery when the nav item is clicked from a page (blog) which then links to the anchor (home).

I have so far got the following code.

```
$('a.nav-link[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

  if (this.hash !== "") {

    event.preventDefault();

    var hash = this.hash;

    var headerHeight = $('.navbar').height();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - headerHeight
    }, 800, function(){

    });
  }
});
```

The smooth scroll works (animate) when on the home page and clicking link (#anchor). When I click a nav item on the blog page (url/#anchor) it will navigate straight to the section id on the home page but with no animation. Also the offset is not taken into consideration which does work when clicking on the anchor link while on the home page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the animation code is also located in the target page?

Comment: the jquery code is running on all pages (wordpress using wp_enqueue_script in functions.php)